# How to get the business "description" via Google Places API?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

In Google Places, when editing my business, I am able to add a "description" under "Basic Information". By the way, to do such an edit go to http://www.google.com/local/add/businessCenter and click "Edit" under the business listing.

When I query the Places API for details of my business, I don't see this "description":

```
url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key=#{key}&sensor=#{sensor}&reference=#{reference}"
```

I looked at [Place Details Results](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details#PlaceDetailsResults), and also don't see a "description" field there.

So how can I get the Place/business description field via a Google API query?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you **own/manage** said businesses, that information is available via Business Profile APIs.

https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations#Location.Profile

You'll want to use the `profile` object.

*Describes your business in your own voice and shares with users the unique story of your business and offerings.*

Answer (score -2):

The question asks "how to get the description" but user continues to describe their problem editing their own business.

It appears that Google does not store Place's descriptions in it's own Google Places DB but instead gives excerpts from relevant Freebase/Wikipedia pages

The answer to editing your business description is "you can't directly" or "create or edit your Wikipedia/Freebase page to indirectly add/modify the description"

Continue reading for the answer on how to "get" the business description using places-api. This example uses PHP.

Many Wikipedia articles do not indicate the lng/lat co-ords so you are unable to do a proximity / name search with the Wikipedia APi.

However FreeBase gets most of it's information from Wikipedia and normally DOES have lat/lng information.

```
//Gather info from Google Places API
//$_GET['gID'] is the Reference for the Place you want info for.
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?"
        ."reference=".$_GET['gID'] 
        ."&sensor=false"
        ."&key=YOUR KEY";

$results = ProcessCurl ($url);  
$gPlace = json_decode($results);

//Gather info from FreeBase 
$url = "https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?"
        ."indent=true"
        ."&filter=%28all"
        ."+type%3Alocation"
        ."+name%3A%22". urlencode($gPlace->result->name) ."%22"
        ."%28within+radius%3A100ft"
        ."+lon%3A". $gPlace->result->geometry->location->lng
        ."+lat%3A". $gPlace->result->geometry->location->lat ."%29%29"
        ."&output=%28description%29";           
$results = ProcessCurl ($url);  
$FreeBase = json_decode($results);

//ensure we got results from FreeBase
//All we want from FreeBase is the Description
if ($FreeBase->status == "200 OK" && $FreeBase->hits > 0)  {
$member = "/common/topic/description";
$Description = $FreeBase->result[0]->output->description->$member;
print_r ($Description[0]);
```

This example uses the NAME, and LAT/LNG of the Google Place and searches the 'Locations' types of the FreeBase DB for that Name within 100ft of it's Lat/Lng.

I'm sure the code can be made better but it works quite well so far.

ALSO -- something of note - When you do a google search for a 'Place' it appears Google searches FreeBase FIRST then matches that result with a similar Google Places result.
This is why when you search google for a place the result on the right may be named differently than the Google Places result and have a description, however if you use 'near' you will notice that the same place now does not have a description.

For instance -- I'm in London Ontario Canada and I can search 'Fanshawe College' and the result is 'Fanshawe College' including description.. however on the Map applet the pointer is at a Google Place called 'Fanshawe College - London Campus' If I instead search 'fanshawe college near London' which specifies I'm looking for a Place; The result I get it 'Fanshawe College - London Campus' with no description and less info.